# Preventing duplicates in JSON array in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a JSON-typed column in a MySQl table. This column stores an array of integer values, like '[1,2,3]'.

What I want is: when I insert a new value into this array using JSON_ARRAY_INSERT/JSON_ARRAY_APPEND, if the value already exists, simply ignore it.

How can I do this within MySQL? That is, NOT checking duplicates from calling scripts like PHP or Node.js, etc.

Update: I'd prefer to use a built-in MySQL mechanism for this purpose, because if done in external scripts, there would be a small chance that duplicates happen due to race conditions, even if I check against duplicates before storing the data.

Thanks!

Comment: add a constraint to your table.

Comment: what constraint? UNIQUE?

Comment: I'd be tempted to store normalised data instead

Comment: I do store normalized data. However, due to race conditions, there is a small chance that dups might happen if this is done outside MySQL.

Answer (score 3):

Without knowing your exact table structure it's difficult to give a precise answer, but the following queries demonstrate how it's done with variables. You would just need to adapt this according to your columns.

```
set @j='["1","2","3"]';
set @v = "4";
select ifnull(json_search(@j, 'one', @v), @j:=json_array_append(@j, '$', @v));
set @v = "1";
select ifnull(json_search(@j, 'one', @v), @j:=json_array_append(@j, '$', @v));
select @j;
```

Output:

```
["1", "2", "3", "4"]
```

Comment: search only works on strings not int's so if you store an an array of int's, this solution won't work, and it's likely int's will be more common like the op question.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps.

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  id INT,
  js JSON
);
INSERT INTO test (id, js) VALUES (1, '[1,2,3]');
INSERT INTO test (id, js) VALUES (2, '[1,2]');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
select * from test;

| id  | js        |
| --- | --------- |
| 1   | [1, 2, 3] |
| 2   | [1, 2]    |
```

---

**Query #2**

```
UPDATE test
SET js = JSON_ARRAY_APPEND (js, '$', 3)
WHERE id = 1 and not JSON_CONTAINS(js, '3', '$');

UPDATE test
SET js = JSON_ARRAY_APPEND (js, '$', 3)
WHERE id = 2 and not JSON_CONTAINS(js, '3', '$');
```

---

**Query #3**

```
select * from test;

| id  | js        |
| --- | --------- |
| 1   | [1, 2, 3] |
| 2   | [1, 2, 3] |
```

Answer (score 0):

```
set @j='[1, 2, 3]';
set @v=1;
SELECT IF(JSON_CONTAINS(@j, CAST(@v AS JSON), '$') = 1, @j, json_array_append(@j, '$', CAST(@v AS JSON)));
```

OUTPUT:
`[1, 2, 3]`

```
set @j='[1, 2, 3]';
set @v=4;
SELECT IF(JSON_CONTAINS(@j, CAST(@v AS JSON), '$') = 1, @j, json_array_append(@j, '$', CAST(@v AS JSON)));
```

OUTPUT:
`[1, 2, 3, 4]`

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE lc,leng,du INT(50);

DECLARE conc,vb VARCHAR(50);
DECLARE new_array JSON;
SET new_array='[]';

SET lc=0;
SET leng=JSON_LENGTH(first_array);
WHILE lc<leng DO
SET conc=(SELECT CONCAT('$[',lc,']'));

IF JSON_CONTAINS(JSON_UNQUOTE(new_array),CONCAT('"',JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(first_array,conc)),'"'))  THEN
  
   SET du=1;
ELSE
    SET new_array=(SELECT JSON_ARRAY_APPEND(new_array,'$',(JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(first_array,conc)))));
end if;
SET lc=lc+1;
END WHILE;


RETURN new_array;
```

This function returns non duplicate JSON array in MySQL
first array is a `json_array` input parameter